# Facebook Like Popup Position

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

im using the facebook like button.I would like the popup window to open ON TOP of the like button and not below the like button because it would go off screen.

Its in an iframe so padding and margin wont work.Please if you do answer, post entire code.Thx

Answer (score 0):

(function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

[Post](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=927295740617130&set=a.927288707284500.1073741911.100000101372770&type=1) by [Ruby Faye Armas Caguin](https://www.facebook.com/fayyearms0116).

Comment: This is a very low quality answer. Please provide a description about your solution and explain how it solves the problem.